# Demo of Classical Example of a Spin 1/2 System

Tags: quantum-spin, education

I was wondering if there are demos of spin 1/2 systems that anyone knows of. Are there any classical systems that are symmetric under a rotation of $4\pi$ and not $2\pi$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_trick especially the links because you need to *see* it to get it

Comment: A person walking around a Möbius strip will be up side down after $2\pi$ and right side up again after a second trip.

Comment: Also, what you're question is really asking is "Are there any any classical systems with elements that transform as [spinors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) (as opposed to Euclidean vectors)?", and the answer would be yes. However, [spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)) of any value is a purely quantum mechanical phenomenon with no classical analogue. This is analogous to how early Newtonian mechanics had systems describable with vectors, but *electric-field vectors* was not one of them. The pedant in my urges you to edit your question title. ;)